# openvr how to get track controllers correctly (C#)

Tags: c#, openvr

I am using openvr with C# and trying to get the controllers.

All methods require the "trackedDeviceIndex" of the controller but I am not sure how I would get this id the correct way. I looked up the documentation and can only find this method for left or right hand:

```
OpenVR.System.GetTrackedDeviceIndexForControllerRole(ETrackedControllerRole.RightHand)
```

Is there any better way to get all tracked controllers in a list or am I using this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So seems like there is not method for that, but you can loop from 0 to k_unMaxTrackedDeviceCount and check the return value.